# Aonde redirecionar usuários de perguntas cuja resposta é "aprenda AJAX"?

Tags: suporte

Vi várias perguntas aqui no site cuja resposta é algo do tipo "você deve usar AJAX". Em algumas delas, como [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/121788/criar-inputs-para-imagens-din%C3%A2micamente-e-passar-para-servlet-sem-redirecionar-a), o(a) autora(a) até sabe que deve usar essa técnica, mas não sabe por onde começar.

Procurei uma pergunta canônica aqui sobre o assunto, mas minhas buscas não me deram resultados. Pensei em criar uma, mas achei que é possível que exista uma, então resolvi perguntar aqui antes.

Comment: A do link não tem resposta.

Comment: @DiegoF Sim. Eu resposta que eu daria envolveria um link para uma pergunta sobre como usar AJAX, mas não encontrei algo parecido. Por isso vim aqui ver se alguém sabe de alguma, ou saber o que vocês fazem nesses casos.

Comment: Eu costumo ver o @bigown responder esse tipo de pergunta, cuja resposta poderia ser algo amplo ou precisar que o OP entenda fundamentos básicos que demonstra não dominar, indicando links de conteúdo daqui e de outras fontes junto com algumas orientações, assim, ele reduz um pouco a "amplitude" do conteúdo se fosse responder a dúvida em si.

Comment: Acho a idéia de trabalhar numa resposta canônica excelente. Se existe uma que você não conseguiu encontrar, talvez ela não seja tão *canônica* assim :D

Comment: Talvez sejam necessárias umas 5 ou mais canônicas pra ir direcionando o pessoal. Eu sempre vou na tag e peço pra organizar por "Frequentes": http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax?sort=frequent&pageSize=50

Answer (score 9):

Do meu ponto de vista, o principal problema com essas perguntas é que primeiro o autor teria que entender um pouco do assunto para depois reformular a pergunta.

Muitas vezes ele adiciona detalhes que só atrapalham.

A pergunta citada em específico não é sobre AJAX no sentido tradicional e sim sobre várias coisas:

- Adicionar campos dinamicamente
- Fazer upload assíncrono de arquivos
- Como receber isso num Servlet

Uma única resposta canônica não bastaria.

Comentei na pergunta apontando um plugin que faz o que eu entendi que faz o que ele quer: uploads múltiplos de forma assíncrona. É algo que ajuda, mas não responde especificamente à pergunta.

Eu creio que seja possível responder perfeitamente à pergunta de forma objetiva, porém de pelo menos duas maneiras:

1. Usando código nativo

   1. Exemplo simples de como adicionar um `<input>` de arquivo dinamicamente
   2. Exemplo simples de como enviar um arquivo via AJAX
2. Usando plugin

   1. Explicar o básico de como isso funciona, sem exemplos
   2. Citar um plugin e colocar um trecho de código de exemplo

No caso dos Servlets, o ideal seria criar outra pergunta.

---

## Atualização

Depois de analisar a questão aqui no Meta, onde me dei ao trabalho de entender o que foi perguntado, acabei achando por bem responder à pergunta já que vi ser possível condensar o conhecimento de forma razoável em três tópicos.

Para mim, mais uma vez isto prova que muitas vezes quando achamos uma pergunta confusa, vaga ou ampla, na verdade isso pode ser simplesmente pelo jeito que ela está escrita ou por nossa própria dificuldade ou falta de tempo para entendê-la melhor.

Não estou advogando que temos que aceitar qualquer coisa no site, nem que sempre seja culpa de quem lê. Claro que quanto melhor for a pergunta, mais votos e mais respostas ela atrai. Por outro lado, perguntas difíceis de entender (por qualquer motivo) acabam dependendo da boa vontade de alguém com disposição para ir mais a fundo no problema.

Comment: [Aquela resposta sua](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/121823/201) é basicamente uma canônica de primeira. Excelente material pra quem tem uma dúvida genérica. Que chovam votos positivos!

Comment: @brasofilo Obrigado :)